# Performance penalization in (VAR)CHAR vs INT for PKs

Tags: mysql, innodb

My question is really simple:

Is there any performance penalization if I use a `(VAR)CHAR` (let's say `5`) instead of an `INT` in a `MySQL` + `InnoDB` database. If there is, why?

Extra question: If I had to use `(VAR)CHAR` as `PK`, what should I use: `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`? And why?

Comment: @rambocoder No, my question is absolutely not the same. I'm not asking about a natural key. I'm asking about the usage of VARCHAR with completely random data.

Comment: a varchar with random data vs a random int? at the simplest form, you have a data size penalty for character data 5 bytes for 5 non-Unicode characters or 4 bytes for an integer. The more rows that can fit onto a page, the better it should perform. My experience is more with SQL Server, so I will leave the answering up to a MySQL expert.

Comment: CHAR(5) would easily fit in a 3 byte `MEDIUMINT`.  If the data gets large, more of the binary representation would stay in memory at a time.